# Scraping pages through dates by using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape websites which have date in the url, instead of number of pages.

For example:

```
https://mywebsite/category/20201103/
https://mywebsite/category/20201102/
https://mywebsite/category/20201101/
https://mywebsite/category/20201031/
...
```

With the number of pages like 1,2,3 ... I would do something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    with requests.Session() as r:
    my_request = r.get("https://mywebsite/category/1") # pages should run within for loop, in order to move from page to page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(my_request.content, 'html.parser')
```

How could I do something similar going through dates instead of numbers?
The range would be from February 1 2015 till November 3 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with a daterange (`pd.date_range()`)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

daterange = pd.date_range('02-01-2015', '11-03-2020', freq='D')

with requests.Session() as r:
    for date in daterange:
        my_request = r.get(f"https://mywebsite/category/{date.strftime('%Y%m%d')}/") # This converts the date to the string format 'yyyymmdd'
        soup = BeautifulSoup(my_request.content, 'html.parser')
        # .... do what you need to do with every iterarion of soup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.timedelta` to add 24 hours to `datetime` object. Then format the string using `strftime`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime(year=2015, month=2, day=1)
end = datetime(year=2020, month=11, day=3)
t = timedelta(hours=24)

url = 'https://mywebsite/category/{}/'

while d != end:  # or d <= end to include end date
    print(url.format(d.strftime('%Y%m%d')))
    d += t
```

Prints:

```
https://mywebsite/category/20150201/
https://mywebsite/category/20150202/
https://mywebsite/category/20150203/
https://mywebsite/category/20150204/
https://mywebsite/category/20150205/
https://mywebsite/category/20150206/
https://mywebsite/category/20150207/
https://mywebsite/category/20150208/
https://mywebsite/category/20150209/
https://mywebsite/category/20150210/
https://mywebsite/category/20150211/

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [pandas.date_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

```
datelst = pd.date_range(start="2015-02-01",end="2020-11-03", freq='D').to_pydatetime()

for d in datelst:
    print(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').replace('-', ''))

# output
20150201
20150202
20150203
20150204
20150205
20150206
20150207
20150208
20150209
...
```

---

```
datelst = pd.date_range(start="2015-02-01",end="2020-11-03", freq='D').to_pydatetime()

with requests.Session() as r:
    for d in datelst:
        
        my_request = r.get("https://mywebsite/category/" + d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').replace('-', ''))  # pages should run within for loop, in order to move from page to page
        soup = BeautifulSoup(my_request.content, 'html.parser')
```